# unable to sort a node within an xml file using namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to access a node inside an .xml file which uses namespaces and sort it. It is not working and I think that it has to do with the namespaces and not being able to qualify them properly.

I have an index.xml which I use to combine the documents that I need and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="merge.xsl"?>

<pic:catalog xmlns:pic = "pictureCatalog">
    <pic:logo>Logo</pic:logo>
    <Author>User Name</Author>
    <pic:allPhotos>photos</pic:allPhotos>
</pic:catalog>
```

the photos.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pic:photoCatalog xmlns:pic="pictureCatalog">

    <pic:photo>
           <pic:title>Alcazar</pic:title>
           <pic:location>Segovia - Spain</pic:location>
           <pic:date>Jan 2013</pic:date>
           <pic:camera>Sony</pic:camera>
           <pic:resolution>12px</pic:resolution>
           <pic:format>.jpg</pic:format>
           <pic:description>
            Medieval Castle over the hill overlooking the city.
           </pic:description>
    </pic:photo>

</pic:photoCatalog>
```

And my xsl stylesheet looks like this:

```
 <!-- All the photos-->
   <xsl:template match = "pic:catalog/pic:allPhotos">
     <html>
         <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
         </head>
         <body>

        <xsl:for-each select="pic:photoCatalog/pic:photo"><br/>
              <xsl:sort select="pic:location"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="pic:photoCatalog/pic:photo/pic:location"/>
           </xsl:for-each>

         </body>
   </html>
   </xsl:template>
```

Can anyone help?

Bluetxxth

Comment: Define "not working" - what output are you getting vs what do you require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two XML files here, but your XSLT is only applied to index.xml, with no reference to photos.xml anywhere. You would normally excpect to see a **document** reference in the XSLT if you want to access a second XML document.

It looks like the second file name is held in the **pic:allPhotos** element of index.xml, and that you want to access that file and iterate over the photos. In this case, you need to change your **xsl:for-each** to access the document like so

```
 <xsl:for-each select="document(concat(., '.xml'))/pic:photoCatalog/pic:photo">
```

The next issue is that you are outputting a **br** element at this point, before the **xsl:sort** statement. This is not valid as the **xsl:sort** should immediately follow the follow the **xsl:for-each**.

```
<xsl:for-each select="document(concat(., '.xml'))/pic:photoCatalog/pic:photo">
   <xsl:sort select="pic:location"/>
   <br/>
```

Also, your **xsl:value-of** is not quite right. As the point this is called, you are in the **xsl:for-each** loop, and so positioned on a **pic:photo** element already, so it can be just simplified to this

```
<xsl:value-of select="pic:location"/>
```

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:pic="pictureCatalog" exclude-result-prefixes="pic">

   <xsl:template match="/pic:catalog">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="pic:allPhotos"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="pic:catalog/pic:allPhotos">
      <html>
         <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css"/>
         </head>
         <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="document(concat(., '.xml'))/pic:photoCatalog/pic:photo">
               <xsl:sort select="pic:location"/>
               <br/>
               <xsl:value-of select="pic:location"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which outputs the following

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body><br>Segovia - Spain</body>
</html>
```

Your namespaces are all present and correct, by the way! (Well, assuming you have declared it corrected on the **xsl:stylesheet** too)

Comment: Thank you much!  It works perfect now... I just wanted to point out one last thing... I had tested wits this expression as you have pointed out:
`<xsl:for-each select="document(concat(., '.xml'))/pic:photoCatalog/pic:photo">`  

but I had this in my value of:
`<xsl:value-of select="/pic:photoCatalog/pic:photo/pic:location"/>`

I gave up on it because it did not work ... is there any other way to write the value of expression than the short cut which you mentioned? 
`<xsl:value-of select="pic:location"/>`

Thank you